# Recursive array method returning 0 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have taken the tip I got from my last question and went deep into debugging my code. I'm still trying to make a method that takes two multidimensional arrays n*n and multiplies them, as if they were matrices. But I have encountered an odd obstacle. This is my code:

```
public class subMatrix {

    public int[][] divcon(int[][] a, int[][] b, int sub) {

        int[][] matrixC = new int[a.length][a.length];

        if (sub == 1) {
            matrixC[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0];

        } else {
            sub = sub / 2;

            int[][] smalla11 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla12 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla21 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla22 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb11 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb12 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb21 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb22 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallc11 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallc12 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallc21 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallc22 = new int[sub][sub];

            for (int i = 0; i < sub; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < sub; j++) {

                    smalla11[i][j] = a[i][j];
                    smalla12[i][j] = a[sub + i][j];
                    smalla21[i][j] = a[i][sub + j];
                    smalla22[i][j] = a[sub + i][sub + j];

                    smallb11[i][j] = b[i][j];
                    smallb12[i][j] = b[sub + i][j];
                    smallb21[i][j] = b[i][sub + j];
                    smallb22[i][j] = b[sub + i][sub + j];

                }
            }
            smallc11 = addMatrix(divcon(smalla11, smallb11, sub), divcon(smalla12, smallb21, sub), sub);
            smallc12 = addMatrix(divcon(smalla11, smallb12, sub), divcon(smalla12, smallb12, sub), sub);
            smallc21 = addMatrix(divcon(smalla21, smallb11, sub), divcon(smalla22, smallb21, sub), sub);
            smallc22 = addMatrix(divcon(smalla21, smallb12, sub), divcon(smalla22, smallb22, sub), sub);
        }
        return matrixC;
    }

    public int[][] addMatrix(int[][] aadd, int[][] badd, int size) {
        int[][] c = new int[size][size];

        for (int d = 0; d < size; d++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < size; e++) {

                c[d][e] = aadd[d][e] + badd[d][e];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The matrices a and b are turned into quarters. I have debugged my code with two matrice inputs 4x4 with the value 2 in each field. Until a certain point, things are going the right way. But if I add a `System.out.println()` to see the return values from `smallc11`, 12, 21 and 22, it sometimes shows as 0. How come? I'm never inputting any 0, and the arrays should not go lower than 1 in length which is 2.

Comment: Note that this problem would generally be solved more easily with simple nested lists...

Comment: The default value of all the elements of int array is 0 so check whether you have set the any value successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `matrixC` but you are not altering it anywhere, so it will be full of `0`.

You can copy the results from all your sub-matrixes, but the simpler thing to do is not create them in the first place.  Just add all the elements of the two original matrixes together will be simpler and faster.

Something like

```
public double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
     assert a[0].length == b.length;
     double[][]c = new double[a.length][b[0].length];
     for(int i = 0, len1 = a.length; i < len1; a++) {
         for(int j = 0, len2 = b[0].length; j < len2; j++) {
              double sum = 0.0;
              for(int k = 0, len3 = b.length; k < len3; k++)
                  sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
              c[i][j] = sum;
         }
     }
}
```

The reason this is much faster is the cost of creating new objects and copying values exceeds the cost of the `*` and `+`.

You can optimise this further by transposing `b` first to improve cache friendliness.

Comment: About my way of solving this code, it has to be this way - in our Algorithm class, we were asked to implement this code, and then implement another code, and compare runtime and algorithm analyzis. Its an extremely hard way, indeed :P ... About your answer - Oh my Gooood, I cant believe this is why it failed. Such a small and annoying part I totally should have seen myself. Did a similar code to turn the smallcs to matrixC as I did to turn matrix a and b into quarters. I get the right results out now :D Ill check with other numbers. But thanks a lot to all for helping me with this one! :)

Comment: In that case I would copy the result back to matrixC when you are finished (before you return).  BTW You can avoid performing the copy back and forth by passing variables to say where in the matrix you want to access. This will still be much slower.  If you want to compare another way, try a Fork-Join implementation which at least might be faster.

Comment: An example of using Fork-Join for matrix multiplication http://pastebin.com/3LikRdPK Google for more and explanations.

Comment: The other code I have to implement is actually just by passing variables about the matrice index.. Its these two versions we are required to use. Ill look into Fork Join anyway though, thanks :))